# How to assign the javascript variable value to php variable

Tags: php, javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to pass JavaScript variables to PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1917576/how-to-pass-javascript-variables-to-php)

I want to assign the javascript variable to php variable

```
$msg = "<script>document.write(message)</script>";
$f = new FacebookPost;
$f->message  = $msg;
```

But it is not working......

Comment: I believe if you explain the situation a little more we can surely help.

Comment: `message` is a javascript variable containing some value. I want to assign this value in php variable.. –

Comment: It seems like you're misunderstanding.  PHP runs on the server, Javascript runs on the client.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Javascript works on the user's computer, PHP works on your server. In order to send variables from JS to PHP and vice versa, you need communication such as a page load.

Have a look here on what you can do: [How to pass JavaScript variables to PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1917576/how-to-pass-javascript-variables-to-php) or more specifically the first answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/1917626/1311593)

Answer (score 6):

PHP is executed before javascript. You can't do that. PHP is server based, JavaScript is client based.

When PHP is finished executing, it outputs HTML. In the HTML there can be JavaScript code also. So PHP can 'control' JavaScript by outputting JavaScript code to the page, but not the other way around. You'd have to use Ajax-call for that.

Answer (score 1):

Javascript, is a client side script, Where as `PHP` is a server side script.

The only way you can send data to PHP is through `redirection` or `ajax`.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do that this way. You have to transmit values *via* `$_GET`, `$_POST` or `$_COOKIE`, *after* the script has been executed by client.